# Run an .exe using mono with MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU set

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have a c# application which I run inside a linux box using mono. I use the command , `sudo mono test.exe`.I figured after a huge load, mono starts running at 100% CPU. As a fix, I'm trying to use MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU environmental variable to a large value. Appreciate the help on how to run the application with an environmental variable set using mono.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable e.g.:

export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2048